# Host console application in windows service

Tags: windows-services, exe, host

I have a console application which i need to host as an independant windows service.

Any idea how to do that. I was able to register the service but when i try to start it, it gives me error :

Error 1053: the service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Services have to call specific WIN32 APIs to integrate with the Service Control Manager (SCM). This includes being able to receive service commands like stop).

An executable that doesn't call these APIs shortly after startup won't work. Ie. a service needs to be specifically written to be a service. (Note, in .NET this is done by extending `ServiceBase` rather than P/Invoking the Win32 APIs).

If you cannot modify the exe you have, consider creating a separate service exe that integrates with the SCM and launches/closes your console application.